# Multiple overlapping subplots with different ranges of data

Tags: python, plot, graph

I have some data that I would like to plot on one figure directly on top of each other. One set has a different y range. It seem I can either plot two sets with the same y-range using `plt`, or two sets with different ranges using `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`, but not all three. Is there some sneaky way of doing it?

Edit:

Apparently it's not as easy as it seemed from the answer!

```
def plot_data2(a = 0 , b = 0, c = 0 ):
  fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (18,8))
  ax2 = ax1.twinx()
  ax1.plot(a, 'b')
  ax1.plot(b, 'g')
  ax2.plot(c, 'r')

  fig.tight_layout()
  plt.show()

plot_data(a=data1, b=data2)
```

[image]

So while I can now print three graphs together just fine. I'd like to be able to also choose to only print any two.

I was going to ask why the axes weren't scaled, but now as I'm typing it, I realize that it's because I assigned the default to 0, so it stretches the graph. Is there any way to only print two graphs and have them both scaled to fit? As well as update the axes labels accordingly. I guess I could write a couple `if`'s inside the function, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

Oh, and one more thing! How about BOTH x and y ranges different?

Comment: Might be useful: `https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html`

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]

data = [
    [(6-x)  for x in X],        # Decreasing
    [3      for x in X],        # Horizontal
    [(10*x) for x in X]         # Increasing
]

print(data)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(X, data[0])
ax1.plot(X, data[1])
ax2.plot(X, data[2], 'r')       # This is the dataset with a different y range
                                # Specify a color otherwise you'll get duplicated colors
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Where blue = `data[0]`, orange = `data[1]`, red = `data[2]` (on a different y axis).

Comment: I think @Raksha is looking for 3 different y-axis, not just 2.

Comment: I guess I interpret "*One set has a different y range*" differently.

Comment: yes there is the confusion. It also mentions "two sets with different ranges using ax2 = ax1.twinx(), but not all three". So, would be looking for answers related to 3 y-axes. Let's leave on her!

Comment: This works too! :) Yes, I only have one set with different y-range, but it's good to know how to handle the case with multiple. Both great answers, thanks, guys!

Comment: @jedwards, I updated the question a little. You wouldn't happen to also be able to help me with that, would you? :)